# Clearing Graphs in R-Studio

Tags: r

So I was trying to clear the graphs in R-Studio. I first cleared the work-space and then tried clearing the graphs but now I am not getting any graphs to appear!!

```
rm(list=ls()
dev.off()
```

Here are the following remedies I have used to get my graphs to appear again:

```
old.par <- par(mar = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
par(old.par)
getOption("device")
```

But none of my graphs are showing up. What's going on!! I appreciate any feedback. Thank you!

Comment: Why not restart your R session in RStudio? There's a menu option to do so.

Comment: Hi Scott, I did. The issue didn't go away.

Comment: In the box to the bottom right where the graphs appear. The software recognizes a graph there. It's just totally white/blank. Nothing is charted.

Comment: Can you post the code that follows your code to clear everything, the code that is supposed to crate a graph but is not?